# Ajax search result and jQuery Masonry plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-masonry

I want to use jquery masonry plugin and ajax function to show result of user's search.

I get the data and adds them to the container and  I call masonry functions. But it doesn't work properly. Here is my simple code:

```
<div id="container">
</div>

<script>
var $container = $('#container');
$container.masonry({itemSelector : '.boxes',isFitWidth: true });

$.get("ajax.php?s=searcStr", function(data){
$container.append( data ).masonry( 'appended', data , true);
$container.masonry( 'reload' );
</script>
```

and output of ajax.php?s=searcStr is something like :

```
<div class="boxes">...</div>
<div class="boxes">...</div>
<div class="boxes">...</div>
```

do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

}); missing in the end of the script?